# PHP json_decode special characters and emoji

Tags: php, json, twitter, emoji

I seem to be having an encoding issue.  I am getting json from the Twitter API v1.1.  The JSON string looks fine. It contains emoji. Then when I json_decode with PHP, the emoji are not coming across correctly.  What am I overlooking?

Here is a reduced test case:

```
<?php
$json = '{"text":"Here is an emoji \ud83d"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);

echo($json);  //returns  {"text":"Here is an emoji \ud83d"}
echo($array['text']); //returns  Here is an emoji í ½
?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What PHP version are you running?

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  Thanks for replying.  The above results are from 5.4.4.  (A solution compatible with that would be nice, but if json_decode() works differently in newer versions of PHP, that would be helpful to learn, as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the character encoding before the output

```
...
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo($json);  //returns  {"text":"Here is an emoji \ud83d"}
echo($array['text']); //returns  Here is an emoji
```

Comment: Thanks, Musa.  Question: setting the character encoding as you describe gets me from:   "Here is an emoji í ½"   to:  "Here is an emoji ���"  Is there an encoding that will preserve: "Here is an emoji \ud83d" ?

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid character?

Comment: Ugh!  You are right, Musa.  I never actually had a problem.  The escaped unicode I was using to troubleshoot with was malformed :(  I'm sorry to you and to stackoverflow, in general.  Oops.  Thanks so much for spotting that for me.